# Can OnItemCommand in Repeater redirect to a new tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to use the Repeater's OnItemCommand to open the aspx page in a new tab (preferably) or a new window. Can it be done with OnItemCommand?

Currently, it redirects to a new aspx page just fine but I stay in the same tab.

Here is my markup code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="someRepeater" runat="server"OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                //bluh bluh
                </HeaderTemplate>

               <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="link1" runat="server" CommandName="Redirect" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("textID") %>'><asp:Label Enable="true" ID="textID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("textName")  %>'></asp:Label></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>


              <FooterTemplate>
            //bluh bluh footer
             </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e){

       if (e.CommandName == "Redirect")
       {
             Response.Redirect("~/Other.aspx?id=" + e.CommandArgument, true);
       }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Opening a new tab is a function of the browser/client side.  Use an HTML link instead of trying to do this in a server side command.  So in your ItemTemplate, build out the link you need and set target="_blank" in the link.

Comment: I ended up using <a href /> in the repeater, built the href, and set target to blank. It provides the functionality that I want. I was just wondering if there is a way to do it with OnItemCommand with Response.Redirect or some other way...Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post how I proceeded with my code. May be it will be of use to someone.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="someRepeater" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                //bluh bluh
                </HeaderTemplate>

               <ItemTemplate>
<a href= "~/Other.aspx?id=<%#Eval('textID') %>" target="_blank" />
              </ItemTemplate>


              <FooterTemplate>
            //bluh bluh footer
             </FooterTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

This seems to do the trick. I did not use the repeater's OnItemCommand. No code behind needed.

Thank you.